# document.cookie is an empy string, even if some cookies are not httpOnly

Tags: php, security, cookies, https, httponly

In php, I return cookie headers over https, but some cookies are NOT marked httpOnly. Yet, *document.cookie* contains an empty string in the browser when run over https (tested with chrome, firefox, edge).

As an example, I created the following PHP script:

```
<?php
setcookie("c1", "v1", 0, "/", false, false);
setcookie("c2", "v2", 0, "/", false, false);
header("Set-Cookie: c3=v3; expires=0;", false);
header("Set-Cookie: c4=v4; expires=0; SameSite=Strict; Secure", false);
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display_here"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("display_here").textContent = '"' + document.cookie + '"';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first two cookies are created with the standard setcookie() PHP function. The last two I create directly by setting the header, so I have more control over what is returned.

The javaScript line at the bottom shows document.cookie is empty. If I inspect the cookies in Chrome (with the dialog), they all exist. However, they are not available to the script. According to RFC 6265 they should be available.

Note that the problem *only* occurs when running over an https connection. When I use http, it works, but that pretty useless.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Doesn't expires=0 mean that the cookie is removed immediately?

Comment: The `expires` option in `header()` needs to be a date-time string, not a number.

Comment: `setcookie()` with 0 expiration is a session cookie.

Comment: The `setcookie()` calls seem to omit the `$domain` argument, which is not optional when more arguments are given, so the first `false` ends up as value for `$domain` I think.

Comment: I ran your code and got all 4 cookies over HTTPS, the first 3 over HTTP.

Comment: I got all the cookies too, but not in document.cookie, so not accessible to javascript

Comment: @Barmar As for the `expires` argument, it is a date-time string in the `Set-Cookie` header, but not in the `setcookie()` call, which takes a number of seconds. PHP converts that internally to a date-time string.

Comment: @trincot You are right. In the original site code from which I scaled down the problem, I do include the domain. It makes no difference.

Comment: @Evert in `setcookie()` it indicates a session cookie.

Comment: I got them in `document.cookie`. Put your code in a test web page, and it showed all my cookies in the DIV, including the 4 that are set here.

Comment: @barnar That's weird. Which browser/version are you using?